# Log-normal mean and standard deviation change after sampling

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, lognormal-distribution, scipy

I have the log-normal standard deviation and the mean that I want to use to sample from a log-normal distribution in Python. However after I do the sampling and compute the arithmetic mean and standard deviation I don't get the same values that plugged in. This only happens when the mean is too small, but for my case I have to work with this exact mean. Any idea on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

here's the code :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from statistics import mean
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
from math import exp
N=1000000
m = 1.75917e-7
siglog = 1.510297984
sigma= np.sqrt(np.log(1 + (siglog/m)**2)) #normal std
mu= (np.log(m) - sigma**2 / 2) #normal mean
f = stats.lognorm.rvs(sigma, loc=0, scale=exp(mu), size=N)
print(mean(f), np.std(f))
```

I get this result : 2.6542845542733312e-08 6.413511018978618e-06
which is very different from siglog and m.

Comment: Just a remark: numpy has its own functions `np.exp`, `np.mean` and `np.std`.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is that you have reversed the roles of the SD and the geometric SD in the formulas.**  How can one tell?  It's just not plausible that any realistic distribution of positive support could have a mean near $0.0000002$ and a standard deviation of $1.5;$ whereas a *geometric standard deviation* of $1.5,$ although high, is not unusual in some applications.

By definition, $X$ has a Lognormal distribution with parameters $(\mu,\sigma)$ when $Y = \log(X)$ has a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$  Writing $m$ and $s$ for the mean and SD of $X,$ respectively, we may compute that

$$m = \exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2).$$

and

$$s = m\sqrt{\exp(\sigma^2)-1}.$$

Your code specifies $m$ and $\sigma$ -- the mean of $X$ and the SD of $Y.$  Therefore the underlying Normal mean is

$$\mu = \log(m) - \sigma^2/2.$$

Here is the fixed code and its output, whose close agreement with the intended parameters also confirms there are no problems with floating point precision.  (Notice the use of `norm.rvs` for this test.  As a rule, I do not use any platform's method to generate lognormal variates, because the conventions about specifying parameters are so varied and confusing.  I always generate normal variates and exponentiate them, because then I know what I'm getting.)

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean
from scipy.stats import norm
N = 1000000
m = 1.75917e-7                        # Lognormal mean
sigma = 1.510297984                   # Normal sd
s = m * np.sqrt(np.exp(sigma**2) - 1) # Lognormal sd
mu = (np.log(m) - sigma**2 / 2)       # Normal mean
params = (mu, sigma)
np.random.seed(17)
x = np.exp(norm.rvs(*params, size = N))
print('Mean (sim): {:06.4g}'.format(mean(x)), ' Mean: {:06.4g}'.format(m), 
      ' SD (sim): {:06.4g}'.format(np.std(x)), ' SD: {:06.4g}'.format(s))
```

> ```
> Mean (sim): 1.756e-07  Mean: 1.759e-07  SD (sim): 5.271e-07  SD: 5.215e-07
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in R and got very similar results to you, even when I tried sampling from the corresponding normal then exponentiating.

The issue here is the scale of the values you're trying to sample. Here's a plot of the density of lognorm(mu = 5.650763, sigma = -31.51881), which are the parameters corresponding to your `m` and `siglog`:

[image: Lognormal density plot]

When you're this close to the machine epsilon, weird things start to happen. For example:

```
> 1 + 2e-16 == 1
[1] FALSE
> 1 + 1e-16 == 1
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: the input data is something I cannot change. Maybe some other sampling method ? Any idea how to go around this issue ? I've been stuck for a while now.

Comment: Where does this data set come from? From a back-of-the-envelope calculation, a (non-negative) sample with this mean and standard deviation is like $10^{14}$ observations that are very close to 0, and a single data point at around $10^7$.

Comment: This data was extracted from Ecoinvent database, a software used in modelling Life cycle assessment of a product. The case of the mean being this negligible compared to the standard deviation is pretty a standard thing to find in life cycle assessment. Please see page 1532 in this reference : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11367-016-1101-1